# python function with the same name being called based on user input

Tags: python, function, keyword

hello i am trying to call a function or functions based on the user input. here is what i have written so far.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
def keyword(a):
  print("what is the boss")
def keyword(b):
  print("who is the boss")
def keyword(c):
  print("where is the boss")


key_words=["what","who","where","when","why"]
x= input("ask.. ").split()
for a in x:
   if str(a) in key_words:
      keyword(key_words.index(a))
```

that is my code i am stuck please help. the problem is that it is not selecting the correct function

Comment: So, those three functions all called `keyword` at the top? When the program executes, **only the last one of those** can get used. Each time you set up a new function with the same name, it _overwrites_ any previous function by that name.

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one function (variable) with the same name. For your example, use dictionaries:

```
keywords = {
    "what": lambda: print("what is the boss"),
    "who": lambda: print("who is the boss"),
    "where": lambda: print("where is the boss"),
}

words = input("ask.. ").split()
for word in words:
   if word in keywords:
      keywords[word]()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generally speaking **not** how functions work at all (there are certain exceptions, but nothing remotely resembling your case).

What would achieve your wish would  be *one* function which prints result based on argument passed to it.

Like this:

```
def keyword(a):
    if a == 0:
        print("what is the boss")
    elif a == 1:
        print("who is the boss")
    elif a == 2:
        print("where is the boss")
```

The rest of the code can be the same, except you don't need the setting of a, b, c variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by Andrew, your function was overwriting the previous. This can do what you wanted to output, but maybe not what you were trying to learn.

```
def keyword(word):
  print(word + " is the boss")

#key_words=["what","who","where"]
x= input("ask.. ").split()
for a in x:
    if str(a) in key_words:
        keyword(a)
```